# ResNet50: high validation accuracy but poor performances in recall, precision and f-1 score

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, resnet

Good evening everyone.

I'm currently working on a project aiming at diagnose Covid-19 from X-ray images.

I do not understand why I obtain great results in terms of validation set accuracy, but very poor performance in terms of recall, precision and f-1 score.

It is a 4 classes classification problem.

[Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8UX2.png)

[Precision, Recall & f-1 score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH5kL.png)

Please, let me know if you need other details to answer me.

Thank you very much in advance to everyone who will try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which dataset you used, but this could be because of an imbalanced dataset. Accuracy can be a misleading measure if the dataset is imbalanced, if that's the case, F1 score is a better metric. Check out [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/accuracy-vs-f1-score-6258237beca2) article for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Dataset Source: https://www.kaggle.com/tawsifurrahman/covid19-radiography-database

You're right, it is quite unbalanced: I cannot attach the distribution graph, but consider that Class 1 (COVID) has 3616 elements, Class 2 (Lung Opacity) has 6012 elements, class 3 (Normal) has 10192 elements and finally, Class 4 (Viral Pneumonia) has 1345 elements.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @MattiaAndreolli I would consider that an imbalanced dataset, so I would rely on F1 score as an accurate metric. My advice is to try to improve your model by tuning the hyperparameters of your network or try to preprocess the images somehow (sorry, can't help much there I know only text preprocessing techniques), and see if that helps with achieving a higher F1 score. No problem friend, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Preprocessing definitely improved the results. Now I have 0.97 of F1 score in the Covid class and 0.94 in the other classes. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MattiaAndreolli Congratulations man, that's a great result! Glad it helped, good luck with your work.